# Mozilla/ Firefox CSS issues compared to webkit

Tags: css

I have designed a search box.

In Chrome/ Safari and IE, it displays as I want.

However, in Firefox, the search button isn't inline.

The code is

```
.form-search .button {
left: 356px;
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
```

Is there a way to add a -moz- line of code to set the left and top just for firefox?

EDIT - MORE CODE AND IMAGES

```
.form-search {
    background: url("../images/searchbox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    border: 0;
}
.form-search .button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 356px;
    top: 4px;
}
.form-search .input-text {
    color: #847D7D;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 230px;
    border: 0;
}
```

That is the entire CSS for the search facility.

[Firefox display](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/97/28235186.png/)

[IE display](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/25933989.png/)

Thanks

Comment: There *is* a simple way to provide CSS to only Firefox. But, you shouldn't *need to* for this.. You should show us more of your "search box" so we can suggest a better fix.

Comment: I have updated the question :) the input text part is having similar problems too!

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo showing the problem? With that, it should be quick to fix :)

Comment: All done, http://jsfiddle.net/ZhNHG/   In FF on that, it is showing as being fine! Hmmmm

Comment: @Luke You are printing the php variable in between the inputs , otherwise its working fine in FF

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because your elements are lacking `display: inline-block;` and you maybe should use relative positioning for this.